# check adjacent (with extra conditions)

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement, indexing

I have a 4x4 table to make from a list (not yet done) and I have to ask the user to input a number at a location (eg, b1,c2, column then row) but for the 2nd number (and onwards) the user has to put it adjacent to another number or else 'it is not allowed' will be displayed and it will prompt the user to input the location again. how do I do this with indexes?

I was thinking of doing this

but I don't know how to write the indexes to check for the above, below, right and left >< I only know the basic things cuz I just started but here's my code

```
num_list = ['1','2','3','4','5',]
import random
num = random.choice(num_list)

table = [[' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']]

ss = {"W1":[0,0],
                    "W2":[1,0],
                    "W3":[2,0],
                    "W4":[3,0],
                    "X1":[0,1],
                    "X2":[1,1],
                    "X3":[2,1],
                    "X4":[3,1],
                    "Y1":[0,2],
                    "Y2":[1,2],
                    "Y3":[2,2],
                    "Y4":[3,2],
                    "Z1":[0,3],
                    "Z2":[1,3],
                    "Z3":[2,3],
                    "Z4":[3,3]}



ans = input('where would you like to place it: ')

if above == ' ' and lower == ' ' and rightside == ' ' and leftside == ' ':
    print('Number must be placed adjacent to another number!\nPlace Where?')
    repeat that turn and ask user to place again and check for adjacent again

else:
    index_ = ss[ans][0]
    columns_ = ss[ans][1]
    table[index_][columns_] = num
    print(table)
```

Comment: What is ```above/lower/rightside/leftside```?

Comment: It's supposed to be the spaces that are around the input location! If the user wants to put the number at B2 then I have to check above, below, left and right of B2 but that's my problem :( I'm not sure how to check those locations

Comment: Some time ago I wrote a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68500919/15035314) to what I think is a similar question. Perhaps you might find it useful in some part

Comment: hello thank you!! but it's a little too confusing for me :( I think its similar but I haven't learnt that far ahead so I don't really understand it, but thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if u have a 4x4 table you can implement that as a 2D array AKA a list of lists like this using a list comprehension (you can do this without list comprehensions aswell):

```py
table = [['' for j in range(4)] for i in range(4)]
```

as for checking neighbours you can have a helper function which checks if a coordinate is valid
like so:

```py
def valid(x: int, y: int) -> bool:
    return 0 <= x < 4 and 0 <= y < 4
```

Now you could have a function which checks all neighbours of the chosen cell of the user and check if they are valid and if so if they are empty. I will leave this part for you but remember that a chosen cell is acessed like this: `list[y][x]` so you can increase/decrease `y` and `x` to check neighbouring cells. Feel free to draw a table in paint and see how you can achieve this.

Edit:
First of all the `->` is part of a thing called [type annotations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html), which are an optional thing you can add to functions and function parameters to make it more clear what the function expects as input and what it outputs, in this case the function outputs a boolean value hence `bool` and `x` and `y` are ints. I assume u understood the purpose of the function (If not say and I will explain it). With regards to the input I would if possible just go for something like this x,y if you have control of the input format. assuming you want the format of b1, c2... where the letter is the `y` value and the number is the `x` value you can go for something like this.

```py
spot = input()
y = ord(input[0]) - ord('a')
x = spot[1]
```

What the `ord()` function does is take a character and converts it into an integer value using [unicode encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode). The key detail here is that the letters a-z are of ascending numeric order with `a=97, b=98` and so forth. Using this we can convert the ord() value of the letter to a `y` value we can use in our table 2D array.

Now that we have the x,y coordinates we can acess the chosen cell like I described before :

```
cell = table[y][x]
```

Now to check the neighbours we can say that:

`table[y][x-1]` corresponds to the left of the cell

`table[y][x+1]` corresponds to the right of the cell

`table[y-1][x]` corresponds to the top of the cell

`table[y+1][x]`corresponds to the bottom of the cell

Now all you need to do is check if this coordinates on the table are valid using the function we wrote before and if they are empty/not empty.

If u have any further questions feel free to ask.

Comment: hi! thank you for the answer!! I've only learnt the basics for now so I don't really understand the def valid portion :( what does the -> bool mean? and if the user inputs X2, do I use the [1,1] and say [1-1,1] to check the above? sorry for the trouble :(

Comment: I will edit the answer for a detailed answer. @cherrynote

Comment: Can I clarify for the function, does the x : int and y : int mean that it's converting the two values to an integer? and that it should be a boolean value? Also, I'm not sure as to where to place each part >< I've tried it but got a list not in range for the checking neighbours portion! I haven't learn how to tell what the errors mean so can I trouble you to explain that as well? so sorry for all the questions, but thank you so much :)

Comment: The x:int and y:int simply tells you and other people reading the code the type you expect the variable to be, however it does not do anything else. It is merely for improving the readability of the code and as such does not gurantee that the input will actually be an int or convert it by itself. With regards to the `bool` part it just says what type the functions returns but does not enforce it. Can you clarify what exactly you didn't understand as i'm not sure what you mean by "><". Do you mean the `valid()` function ? or something else.

Comment: ohh I see, so it's for better understanding? I mean I tried using the code but I got an error! Is it because I'm using a dictionary to obtain the coordinates? or did I not piece the code together properly?

Comment: I assigned the codes top = table[y-1][x] and so on but I got a IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Using the method i provided there is no need for a dictionary at all as we implement the table with a 2D array and check the neighbours as i described. There is just no need for a dictionary in this case. If u need further clarification feel free to ask.

Comment: You should use the `valid()` function I wrote to validate if the coordinates are valid when checking the neighbours. for example `if valid(x - 1 ,y) and table[y][x-1]: do something`.

Comment: I did the 2D array and it worked!! But I'm still not very sure on how it works? I don't have a very good understanding on loops in general. also can I know if there's a way to repeat? Eg, this happens on the 3rd turn: print('Number must be placed adjacent to another number!\nPlace Where?') after I print this, I would like for the user to be able  to repeat that 3rd turn again instead of moving onto the next

Comment: Glad to hear it worked. You can think of a 2D array as an array of arrays, try to draw it on a piece of paper or in paint and work out why it makes sense. With regards to repeating u can use a `while` loop. In a nutshell it is a loop that runs untill a condition is satisfied. You should seek out more information on this type of loop and the `for` loop aswell though in this particular instance a `while` loop will serve you better. Feel free to ask more if u want.

Comment: I'll try to draw it out for better understanding! :) From my knowledge, while loop is used like while variable > 2: do something? and for loop is using range of a list? and nested loops will run through the elements in a nested list? Is that right? I tried looking for more simple examples because it wasn't covered much during lessons

Comment: Yeah `while` loops can be used like the example you provided, with whatever conditions you want. I will add that there are keywords which can be used inside loops which are `break` which basically quits the loop immediately and `continue` which skips to the next iteration of the loop. Regarding what u said about `for` loops for the most part yes they are mostly used to iterate over things like lists, sets, etc like so : `for item in list`, This type of `for` loop is sometimes called a for each loop as you are doing something for each item in the collection.

Comment: Nested loops are basically the same as non nested loops but you just iterate over two things at a time so let's say you want to iterate over every item in a 2D array you could do something like this:
`
for row in array:
    for cell in row:
        # Do something
`
However notice that you can also use non nested loops to iterate over nested arrays if your use case justifies it for example let's say you have a tic tac toe board and you want to check the main diagonal you could do something like this:
`
for i in range(len(array)):
    symbol = array[i][i]
`

Comment: Thank you so much!! I think I have a better understanding now :) I'll try to implement the part where I repeat the turn with the while loop. I also have to create a score list based on where the numbers are placed and I'm assuming it needs to use loops as well? I'll try to do it on my own but is it okay to ask you for help if I get stuck?

Comment: Well i'm not sure about how you want to create the scores list but if u run into trouble maybe it would be better to create a seperate question and if u want you could leave me a comment here and i'll check it out. Anyhow you are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Like @CryptoNoob said you can use a 2D list but for finding the coords you can use a function that uses math:

```
def check(the_square):
    squares = []
    row = the_square[0]
    col = the_square[1]
    int(row)
    int(col)
    upper_sqr = [row-1, col]
    lower_sqr = [row+1, col]
    right_sqr = [row, col+1]
    left_sqr = [row, col-1]
    squares.append(upper_sqr)
    squares.append(lower_sqr)
    squares.append(right_sqr)
    squares.append(left_sqr)
    return squares
```

In squares are the coords for [above, lower, rightside, leftside]. If the square is on the edge there will be negative coords. The_square is the coords of the square to be checked. This code assumes that the first number is the row and the second is the column. the coords are indexes for a 2d list. How to make a 2D list:[How to make 2D list](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-using-2d-arrays-lists-the-right-way/)

Response to @cherrynote:If you wanted to check column then row yes, you would have to exchange them.

Comment: Thank you so much! :) But my requirements are to check the column then row, so do I exchange the positions for row and column?